# Toggle read more and read less when data exceeds a certain character length in ngFor angular 4

Tags: angular

```
How to add read more for the td content, please help

    <ng-container *ngFor="let list of newList.all;let i = index">
        <tr [class.my-class]="i == selectedRow || currentPlayingId == list.id">
            <td>
                {{list.id }}
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="truncating">
                {{list.filename || list.url || list.eventurl  | truncate : 20}}
            </td>
<button ion-button (click)="truncating = false">show more</button>
 <button ion-button (click)="truncating = true">show less</button>
            <td class="textSize">
                {{list.mode }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

I tried this method, but it wont work in the loop, all  elements 'show more' will work clicking on one element. please help

Comment: Not sure what you mean by read more/less - can you update your question and your example code to explain better?

Comment: toggle read more and read less when data exceeds a certain character length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the hidden attribute on your tr based on a variable

```
<tr [hidden]="!showMore && i > 10" ...
```

And change that variable with a button

```
<button (click)="showMore=!showMore>More/less</button>
```

**Edit**

if you want to do it on the td, you can declare an array of booleans in your component

```
public truncateState: boolean[] = new Array(yourSizeHere);
//fill it with default value
truncateState.fill(false);//or true
```

and in your template use

truncateState[i] instead of truncating

Comment: I edited the answer to add a condition based on the loop index. So it should work to hide/show all rows after the index 10

Comment: Thank you,  but i wanted to add read more for the data in <td> element and not for <tr>

Comment: Thats the same principle

Comment: when using this method, 'show more' is working for the all the <td> elements in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are using just a single variable, so it will toggle all as show more or show less. What you need is a unique boolean value to toggle. So what I would do, is to insert a new property to your object, for example `showMore`

So you can add that property to each of your objects, all you can also add this property on the fly in your template. I would perhaps for consistency add the property initially to all objects, but that is up to you. Then you just toggle that boolean value:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let list of newList.all;let i = index">

  <!-- More code here -->

  <button ion-button (click)="list.showMore = true">show more</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="list.showMore = false">show less</button>

  <div *ngIf="list.showMore">
    <!-- show here -->
  </div>
</ng-container>
```